# In comments, automatic Removal of @name when default?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, comments

Are direct-to-original-poster references not allowed using the @ sign?

In [Win, Wins, or Won?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24764/win-wins-or-won/24765#24765) I attempted to make a comment:

> @BobtheZealot, can you please confirm my comment above?

The system kept reducing this to:

> can you please confirm my comment above?

So I just rewrote it as

> BobtheZealot, can you please confirm my comment above?

Is this a "feature" or an error?  I surely don't like it (from my limited perspective, at this moment in time) because I would like my comment to be clearly directed to Bobthezealot, and to me, "@name" is natural to indicate attention "to whom" I am directing a comment. I know it's redundant from the system's point of view, but I like the style.

Prefacing a name with @ is a standard style for notification to a user.  I'm not sure from where, but surely, via twitter at least, it is now the "de facto standard" to refer to someone using @username.

And from a UI point of view, an automated "correction" with no message seems rather much like a programming function f(x) with an unintuitive side-effect on x.  Wouldn't it be better to error on the submission using javascript?

Comment: Probably related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a "feature", or at the very least by design:

[Eeeeek - what happened to my @ salutation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97098/)

I don't think it's a terribly popular feature, although I might be overinterpreting the grumbling of a select few users :-)  See any of the dupes of the above question, or [this request to fix the feature with almost 200 upvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97283/dont-remove-the-part-of-my-comment).